# Get row index for Antdv table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, antd

All I need to do is to get and pass the row index once I click on a button place in a cell of the `a-table`, I cannot find the solution for it:

```
      <a-table
        :columns="columns"
        :data-source="getRowsData"
        :pagination="false"
        row-key="id"
      >
        <template slot="action" slot-scope="text">
          <a-button type="primary" @click="getRowIndex">
            {{ text }}
          </a-button>
        </template>
      </a-table>
```

Comment: this lacks a lot of details

Comment: there is no show of attempt of how you're trying to use `getRowIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass the record in the scope, and refer it in click function

```
    <template slot="action" slot-scope="text, record">
      <a-button type="primary" @click="() => getRowIndex(record.key)">
        {{ text }}
      </a-button>
    </template>

methods: {
   getRowIndex(key) {
      //do smthg with the key
    },
}
```